# Remove all the characters from string after last '/'

Tags: sed

I have the followiing input file and I need to remove all the characters from the strings that appear after the last '/'. I'll also show my expected output below.

*input:*

```
/start/one/two/stopone.js
/start/one/two/three/stoptwo.js
/start/one/stopxyz.js
```

*expected output:*

```
/start/one/two/
/start/one/two/three/
/start/one/
```

I have tried to use `sed` but with no luck so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use good old `grep`:

```
grep -o '.*/' file.txt
```

This simple expression takes advantage of the fact that `grep` is matching *greedy*. Meaning it will consume as much characters as possible, including `/`, until the last `/` in path.

---

*Original Answer*:

You can use dirname:

```
while read line ; do
    echo dirname "$line"
done < file.txt
```

or sed:

```
sed 's~\(.*/\).*~\1~' file.txt
```

Comment: oh yes thanks alot .. that sed command worked perfect for me .thanks

Comment: Glad to help. Just a hint: You should have been putting more effort into the wording of your question

Comment: ya that is so nice and simple grep commmand .thanks for that one @hek2mgl

Comment: If you provide the right nail, `grep` is a powerful hammer! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this GNU sed command,

```
$ sed -r 's~^(.*\/).*$~\1~g' file
          /start/one/two/
          /start/one/two/three/
          /start/one/
```

Through awk,

```
awk -F/ '{sub(/.*/,"",$NF); print}' OFS="/" file
```

Comment: thanks for the comments . it tried this but it give me some error like 
sed: -e expression #1, char 1 invalid reference \1 on `s' command's RHS

Comment: try `sed 's~^\(.*\/\).*$~\1~g' file`

Comment: @user310685 i think you forget to add `-r` option.

Comment: oh yes right. forgot -r . right sorry my mistake @avinas

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -lne 'print $1 if(/(.*)\//)' your_file
```